# How to port pre-built Perl DBD::Oracle to different location of Oracle libraries?

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi, dbd

DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so hard-codes the location of Oracle's libclntsh.so (and other libraries) to their location at the time of building/installing DBD::Oracle.

I do not want to build and install DBD::Oracle on all servers, but the location of the libraries differs between servers.  Is there any way around this?  Binary patch Oracle.so?

Comment: Reading through `Makefile.PL` maybe the `-l` switch, called "direct linking", could statically link `libclntsh.so` into DBD::Oracle? The documentation is unclear and I can't try it myself...

Comment: Hmmm.  *That* would be interesting.  I'll look into it.